# Is there any way to list available GitHub repositories using ssh?

Tags: github, ssh

I have been using git since i have started my career. I am starting to use ssh more and more, i just want to know is there a way to list all available repositories on git using just my ssh key. So i won't open github's webpage everytime and clone what i want. I find it more convenient using my cli. I have tried `ssh git@github.com` but doesn't seem to work. I want to list like all available repositories be it private or not.

Comment: "but doesn't seem to work" What happens?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice it just says `You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
Connection to github.com closed.` but doesn't let me use command and stuff

Comment: This shows that your key is correct, but as the message says, GitHub does not provide shell access.

Comment: `ssh` itself is just a method for gaining some kind of access to some other host (one that is running `sshd`). Once you *do* gain access, what you can do there depends on what kind of access they gave you. If they give you *shell* access, you could `cd` around the file system and `ls` various directories to look for Git repositories—but GitHub do not give you shell access, so you can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to list available repositories using ssh?

No, not directly. You cannot access a shell on GitHub servers with SSH. This is clearly stated when you try `ssh git@github.com`:

```
> Hi username! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not
> provide shell access.
```

Instead for CLI access to your GitHub resources, install [GitHub CLI](https://cli.github.com/).